# How to filter multiple criteria with not in nodejs & mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and mongodb. In mongo db, there is users collection where the attributes are name and status. Status records have 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D'. I want to filter record within name array and status except 'A'. How to do it?

```
var nameArr = [];
nameArr.push('Jojo');
nameArr.push('Legend');

// The record return null when i added status: !'A'
db.collection('users').find({name: {$in: nameArr},{status: !'A'}}).toArray(function (resp) {
     res.json({code: '00', content: resp});
});
```

**User Schema**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("515fd5f42a84cb610eed23es"),
  "name": "Jojo",
  "status": "A"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("584fd5f42a84cb610eed23ef"),
  "name": "Legend",
  "status": "C"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("585fd5f42a84c1110eed23ef"),
  "name": "Mark",
  "status": "D"
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("585fd5ss42a84cb610eed23ee"),
  "name": "Swish",
  "status": "B"
}
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("584fd5f42a84cb610eed23ef"),
  "name": "Legend",
  "status": "C"
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `user schema`. How your `user` document looks.?

Comment: You can check my answer. It should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going on right track but "`!`" doesnt work in MongoDb.

You can use `$ne` for this:

```
db.collection('users').find({name: {$in: nameArr},status: { $ne :'A'}}).toArray(function (resp) {
     res.json({code: '00', content: resp});
});
```

$ne is an operator for checking `Not Enquals to` in mongoDb.

For more info please go through [MongoDB $ne Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$ne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operator:

Probable query:

```
db.collection('users').find({name: {$in: nameArr}, status: { $ne:  'A' }}).toArray(function (resp) {
     res.json({code: '00', content: resp});
});
```

Comment: $ne stand for what?

Comment: You have a typo in your answer, it should be `status` instead on `state`. Also, I didn't see your answer, meanwhile i was typing.

Comment: @digit $ne stands for Not Equal to

Comment: Ok2. I got it both of you, if i can accept both the answer, i do it but i need to accept the best answer. Thanks u guys.